# operator overloading in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Hi guys can some one please suggest a good tutorial on operator overloading?
I was going through this code on operator overloading and I have the following doubts
**code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Array {

 int *a;
 int size;
 int capacity;

 public:
    Array (int c) {a=new int[c]; size=0; capacity =c; } ;
    Array & operator <<  (int x); 
    int  operator []  (int i) { 
        if (i<size) return a[i] ;
        else  {
            cout <<"Segmentation Fault Prevented!\n"; 
            return -1;
        }
    };
};
Array &Array::operator <<  (int x) { 
   if (size < capacity) a[size++] = x;
   else {
    int *tmp = new int[size+capacity];
    for (int j=0; j<size; j++)
        tmp[j]=a[j];
    delete [] a;
    a = tmp;
    a[size++]=x;
    capacity=size+capacity;
   }
   return *this;

} ; 

int main (int agrc, char *argv[] ) {

 Array b(10);

    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) b << i;
    b << 1 << 2 << 3;
    for (int i=0; i<105; i++) cout << b[i] << endl;
}
```

I have these doubts:

1. Can some one please suggest a good tutorial on operator overloading?
2. what does `Array & operator <<  (int x);` mean?
3. `int operator []  (int i)` - if this is a function why are we putting square brackets here?
4. `Array &Array::operator` means what?
5. what is `*this`?

Please help me...I am new to c++ so have these doubts....
Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: Just search in the site, many similar questions have been asked, and someone even wrote a FAQ on operator overloading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Google is your friend :) or have a look at http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html
2. It overloads the `<<` operator
3. It overloads the `[]` operator, so you can use `yourobject[something]`. It's used e.g. by `std::map`
4. It looks like the beginning of the implementation of an overloaded operator.
5. It's a reference to the current object.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to (1): Did you look at the FAQ? http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html

Comment: yes...its nice i m currently reading it

Answer (score 1):

1. [This](http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/).
2. The operator << is being overloaded to take an integer as an argument, and it returns a reference to an Array class.
3. The operator [] is being overloaded to accept an integer as an argument. It returns an integer.
4. Returning a reference to Array, the operator << belonging to Array
5. `this` is the pointer to the current object, so `*this` dereferences that pointer.

Perhaps you really need [this](http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/) link....

Comment: This one also looks good: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Operators/Operator_Overloading

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you encount `T operatorX`, where `X` can be any of `(),[],<<,>>,+,+=,=,--,++` etc., that's what is called "operator overloading". It does just what it says -- it enables you to use that operator on the class it's overloaded for. For example your array could be accessed like this:

```
Array myArr(10);
myArr[0] == 5;
myArr[1] == 10;
//   ^^^ --- this is using the `operator[]` with an int parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is good one. I used to reference it.

Operator-Overloading/Catalog0200_Operator-Overloading.htm">http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0200_*Operator-Overloading/Catalog0200*_Operator-Overloading.htm

Answer (score 1):

Adding to other answers,this is a nice source to learn operator overloading by examples :-

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0200__Operator-Overloading/Catalog0200__Operator-Overloading.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry can't help more on the first problem, but I refer to 'C++ primer' for some basic concept I'm not clear.

I think operator overloading does not have too much difference between method overloading except for the naming convention. If you know how to overload a method in C++, it's not very difficult to understand operator overloading once you get used to the syntax.

As other Object-Oriented language, in C++, if we want to overload a method, we just declare multiple versions of method to be overloaded with a shared method name and different parameter lists. Operator overloading looks the same in spite of we should know what is the name of the operator(which is equivalent to method name in method overloading). To name an operator, we should first use the keyword **operator** followed by the operator we wanna overload. Take your second question for example: here, we are going to overload the operator <<(the output operator), and we use **operator <<** telling the compiler "That's what I want to overload." Also because an operator is just like a method, it should have a return value. In problem 2, **Array &** is returned, which is an reference to an **Array** type. The **Array** in "Array::opertor <<" means operator << is a member of class Array.

Hope this can give you some hint understanding this code snippet. You can find all the concepts in a definitive C++ tutorial.

Good luck.